# Get Matching entry in array using php

Tags: php, json, api

I need to get a special entry from a json array and it should be matched by id.

```
{
            "response": {
                "count": 62,
                "inventory": [
                    {
                        "id": 10,
                        "style": 982
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 20,
                        "style": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 30,
                        "style": 1
                    }       ]
    }}
```

Everything I have right now is this code:

```
$matching_value = 10;    
foreach($json_data as $key => $val){
    if($val->id == $matching_value){
      echo $val->id;
      echo $val->style;
       }
    }
```

But it is not working and I don't know why. Does my approach not work with sub-entries?

Comment: 1) decode your json string 2) *But it is not working* What does that mean? Do you get an error? `PHP warning code not working on line 3;`

Comment: `$json_data` is the elements in `"response"`, or the elements in `"inventory"`?

Comment: If you're `return $key;`ing before echo'ing, it will never echo... Is that what you were expecting?

Comment: I think you want `foreach ($json_data['response']['inventory'] as $key => $val) {`

Comment: Also, there is ``id`` in JSON, but there also are elements with ``appid`` and without ``id``. This gonna fail as never before.

Comment: thanks for the replies! @Rizier123: when I var_dump($val) ist doesn't show anything..

Comment: @НЛО: i wanted to abstract the data and i forgot to change those two appid to id

Comment: What exactly is `$json_data`? The entire json that you posted? Or what?

Comment: @Zsw: the list goes on for 50 further entries and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

- you need to decode the json string to an array
- inside the foreach, you have used object property access syntax and i've changed that to array access ($val->id ... $val['id'])

> Does my approach not work with sub-entries?

Not like you have it. You would have to test what you are iterating over,
if its a string, int, array. Consider the nesting, etc.
I have reassigned $inventory to make iterating over the inner array a bit easier, gets you closer to the value

Source:

```
// JSON string
$json = '{
    "response": {
        "count": 62,
        "inventory": [
            {
                "id": 10,
                "style": 982
            },
            {
                "id": 20,
                "style": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 30,
                "style": 1
            }
        ]
    }}
';

// debugging
var_dump($json, json_decode($json, true));

// decode json to array
$data = json_decode($json, true);

// prepare iteration

// reassign 
$inventory = $data['response']['inventory'];

$matching_value = 10;

foreach($inventory as $key => $val)
{
    //var_dump($val);

    if(isset($val['id']) && $val['id'] === $matching_value)
    {
      echo 'The ID: ' . $val['id'];
      echo 'The Style' . $val['style'];
    }
}
```

Output:
`The ID: 10The Style982`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your code looks like the missing link to my code. But I get the json array from an url with file_get_contents and json_decode. If I use your code, I only get an internal error. Have you got a solution to this?

Comment: Well, probably an issue of setting the second parameter of json_decode to true. That decides if you get an array or an object, e.g. `$jsonObject = json_decode(file_get_contents('source://json'));`. Just change that to `$jsonArray = json_decode(file_get_contents('source://json'), true);` In short: add true as 2nd parameter to json_decode and then use the code above starting from `// prepare iteration`. | If that doesn't solve the issue, post the error message you get.

Comment: I have used your advices and code, but now I get the internal error 500 error, see my code: `$contents = json_decode(file_get_contents($steam_api_url, true);
$json_data_a = $contents['response']['games'];

foreach($json_data_a as $key => $val)
{
    //var_dump($val);

    if(isset($val['appid']) && $val['appid'] === $steam_game_id)
    {
      echo 'The AppID: ' . $val['appid'];
      echo 'The Time: ' . $val['playtime_forever'];
    }
}`

Comment: Hard to read. Hmm. json_decode is not properly closed with `)` -  `$contents = json_decode(file_get_contents($steam_api_url, true)**)**;` The rest of the code looks ok. You could enable PHPs error reporting or take look at the logs, what the internal error really is.

Comment: Ah yeah, I closed the bracket of the json_decode-command and now the error is gone. But now I don't have any output. I used var_dump to let me show, what I got from the url, but the foreach-loop does not provide any output, although var_dump gives back an object.

Comment: An object? It should be an array. | Did you check that the value you are looking for can be found in the data you are iterating over? If the appid is not in the data, you get no output. | You could activate the var_dump() inside the foreach. That will output the value you are currently iterating over. At least you would have some more debugging output - to check if the appid can be matched.

Comment: Well, I have just rewritten the code with your anotations and I get back an array now. The part I am searching for is also part of it `[44]=> array(3) { ["appid"]=> int(252950) ["playtime_2weeks"]=> int(1647) ["playtime_forever"]=> int(5849) }` I have used in_array() to see, if the value of the appid I am searching ('252950') can be found, but the var_dump tells me bool(false). That's somehow strange..

Comment: Use isset() or array_key_exists() when testing existance of key inside $val

Comment: i finally got my code together. thanks for your help, I used your code for another project and I've learned alot about arrays and debugging thanks to you. Here you can see the code I used to get my searched value: `$ioa = array_search($steam_game_id, array_column($json_data_array, 'appid'));
$json_data_array[$ioa]['playtime_forever']`